# Passing data to next view controller, but data disappears?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableview with cells that each contain a "Concept", CoreData Object. They all have an attribute called html, which are not nil (I checked that by printing in this tableview `viewDidLoad()`). The problem is when I try to pass it in `prepareForSegue` this data kind of disappears.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if segue.identifier == "toConcept"{
        let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = nc.viewControllers.first as! PDFViewController

        print(concepts[(indexPath?.row)!].html
        //This prints nothing.

        vc.html = concepts[(indexPath?.row)!].html
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the `viewDidLoad()` the html is fine and not nothing, but in the prepareForSegue is prints nothing and in the `PDFViewController` it is also gone.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    func tableView(_ messagesListTableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConcept", sender: indexPath)
    print(indexPath)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "toConcept"{
let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath
        let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = nc.viewControllers.first as! PDFViewController

        print(concepts[(indexPath?.row)!].html
        //This prints nothing.

        vc.html = concepts[(indexPath?.row)!].html
        }

}
```